# ¿Cómo guardar posiciones de una matriz en un array con PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy cogiendo ahora mismo las posiciones (los índices) que no coinciden en dicho array.

```
$carsPedro = array (
    array("Volvo",1,13000),
    array("BMW",3,13500),
    array("Saab",2,12000),
    array("Land Rover",4,15000)
  );

$carsMaria = array (
    array("Volvo",1,13000),
    array("BMW",2,13500),
    array("Saab",2,14000),
    array("Land Rover",4,15000)
  );

$changes=array();

  for ($a=0; $a < count($carsPedro); $a++) { 
    for ($b=0; $b < count($carsPedro[$a]) ; $b++) { 
        if($carsPedro[$a][$b] !== $carsMaria[$a][$b]){
            array_push($changes, $a, $b);
        }
    }
}
```

Esto me devuelve ahora mismo

```
array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(2) }
```

No está mal del todo, ya que ahora sí que me devuelve la posición 1,1 y la 2,2; que son las posiciones que difieren entre ambas matrices. El tema es que a la hora de almacenarlo en el array quiero que lo almacene así:

[0]=> 1,1
[1]=> 2,2

Porque ahora mismo, así cómo está, no me vale exactamente, ya que las posiciones tienen dos coordenadas y en cada posición del array ha de guardarse la posición completa (no sólo un 1, y en la siguiente posición otro 1). No sé si me explico. Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Puedes quitar el `array_push` y poner esto en su lugar: `$changes[]="$a,$b";`  o bien ponerlo así: `array_push($changes, "$a,$b");`

Comment: Y esto haría exactamente lo mismo sin tantos bucles: `foreach ($carsPedro as $k=>$subArray){ if (!in_array($subArray, $carsMaria)) { $changes[]="$k,$k"; } }` Lo que no logro entender todavía es para qué quieres los valores apareados realmente ... me temo que hay un error de concepto o de lógica en algún lado, si no sale ahora, más tarde saldrá.

Comment: Posiblemente sea un error de lógica. A ver, el tema es que necesito comparar dos bases de datos (de dos servidores distintos) para poder sincronizarlas. La lógica que estoy aplicando es: 1) Ver en qué posiciones dónde hay diferencias entre las tablas 2) Con un sistema de log, ver qué cambio es más reciente 3) Sobreescribir el dato más antiguo de la tabla correspondiente con el dato más reciente de la otra tabla

Comment: Pues eso, con un sólo `foreach` lo puedes hacer, mete en cada fila el campo fecha y así podrás obtener un sólo array con los datos más recientes.